# develop blackberry webworks phonegap plugin without adding source to cordova.jar

Tags: blackberry, cordova, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-webworks, cordova-2.0.0

I need to develop plugin for blackberry webworks phonegap. But i dont want to add my plugin source files to cordova.jar. I want to create another jar and put it to my projects somewhere inside www folder.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience with Phonegap/Cordova you must place your plugin within their JAR file.  It goes against their standard implementation to add a plugin any other way, and I imagine you'd have a world of trouble getting it to work properly otherwise.

I've never seen it done any other way personally.  Can I ask why you wouldn't want to add your plugin to their JAR???

-Chad

Comment: because there may be updates on cordova.jar or my jar. i did not want to do that way. and after a research i understand that it can be done without putting my source into cordova.jar but it requires much configurations. So i gave up and put my source into cordova.jar :D